# If $U \le G$ has odd order, and $N_G(U) = TU$ with $T = \langle t \rangle$ an involution. Assertions about $S = TU\setminus T^U$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $U \le G$ be a subgroup of odd order of the finite group $G$. Suppose $t \notin T$ is an involution with $u^t \in uU'$ for all $u \in U$, where $U'$ denotes the commutator subgroup of $U$. Further suppose that $U^g \ne U$ implies $U^g \cap U = 1$.

Set $S := TU \setminus T^U$. Then for $g \in G$ we have that $S^g \ne S$ implies $S^g \cap S = \emptyset$ and $N_G(S) = TU$.

How do both statements hold for $S$?

If I can show that $S \le U$, then $S \cap S^g \le U \cap U^g$, so that $S^g = S$ implies for $S \ne 1$ that $U^g = U$, hence $N_G(S) \le N_G(U)$. Of course by definition $t \notin S$, maybe that might help. But I am unable to establish that $S \le U$.

Comment: What does $T^U$ mean exactly?

Comment: The conjugates of $T$ by elements from $U$: $T^U = \{ t^u : t \in T, u \in U \}$.

Comment: I am a little confused because $1 \in T^U$, so $1 \not\in S$, so how can $S^g \cap S =1$?

Comment: Yes, good point! I have this from a paper, there they just state it in written language, i.e. they say $S$ is a trivial intersection set, but if $S$ is just a set without identity the only statement making sense here is to require $S^g \cap S = \emptyset$ if $S^g \ne S$. I edit my question!

Comment: No element of $S$ has order $2$. So for any $s \in S$ some power $s^k$ of $S$ is a nontrivial element of $U$. So $s \in S \cap S^g \Rightarrow s^k \in U \cap U^g$.

Comment: In fact you can take $k=2$ in my previous comment.

Comment: @DerekHolt I found a proof that no element of $S$ has order $2$, but still lacking an argument why $N_G(S) = TU$. How to see that precisely the elements $TU$ normalize $S$?

Comment: That follows follows from my previous comment.

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes, but I can only deduce by that $S = S^g$ implies $g \in N_G(G) = TU$, hence $N_G(S) \le TU$, but I am stuck on the other inclusion $TU \le N_G(S)$. For if $tu\in S$ and $g = tu' \in N_G(U)$, then $t^gu^g = t^{u'}u''$, but I am not sure if this element is still in $S$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just collect, write up and expand whats written in the comments by Derek.

We have
$$
 S = \{ g \in TU : |g| > 2 \}
$$
for suppose $g \in TU$ has order $2$, then $\langle g, t \rangle \le TU$
generates a dihdral group of order $2m$ with $m$ odd, hence all involutions
of this dihedral group are conjugate in $\langle g, t \rangle$ (or using [this statement](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Involutions_are_either_conjugate_or_have_an_involution_centralizing_both_of_them), if $g$ and $t$ are not conjugate, then a third involution $z$ centralizes $g$, then $\langle z, g \rangle = \langle z\rangle\times\langle g \rangle$ and $TU$ would be divisible by four), hence also in $TU$, and as $t^{tu} = t^u$ they are already conjugate in $U$. So no element of order $2$ is contained in $S$. Conversely as $T^U$ just contains elements of order $2$ or $1$, every element left in $S$ has order $> 2$.

Now suppose $s \in S^g \cap S$. Then $s = x^g$ for some $x \in S$. As $U \unlhd TU$ we have $x^2 \in U$, and as $x$ has order $> 2$ we have $x^2 \ne 1$. Similarly $(x^2)^g = (x^g)^2 = s^2 \in U$. So $(x^2)^g \in U \cap U^g$. This gives $U^g = U$. Hence if $S^g = S$ we must have $U^g = U$, or $N_G(S) \le N_G(G)$. For the other inclusion, if $g \in N_G(U)$ and $tu \in S$, then as $(tu)^g$ has the same order as $tu$, with the above description of $S$ we have $N_G(G) \le N_G(S)$.